# how to create custom reports in testng

Tags: java, testng

I have the following Java code:

```
public class Login {
    String Login_Status = null;
    String Login_Message = null;

    @Test
    @Parameters({"USERNAME","PASSWORD"})
    public void Execute(String UserName, String Password) throws IOException {
        try {
            Config.driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log in")).click();
            Config.driver.findElement(By.id("user_login")).sendKeys(UserName);
            Config.driver.findElement(By.id("user_pass")).sendKeys(Password);
            Config.driver.findElement(By.id("wp-submit")).click();
            // perform validation here
            boolean expvalue = Config.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@rel='home']")).isDisplayed();
            if (expvalue) {
                Login_Status = "PASS";
                Login_Message="Login Successfull for user:" + UserName + ",password:" + Password + ",\n EXPECTED: rtMedia Demo Site LINK SHOULD BE PRESENT ON THE HOME PAGE OF rtMedia ACTUAL: rtMedia LINK is PRESENT ON THE HOME PAGE OF rtMedia. DETAILS:NA";
            }
        } catch(Exception generalException) {
            Login_Status = "FAIL";
            Login_Message = "Login UnSuccessfull for user:" + UserName + ",password:" + Password + ",\n EXPECTED: rtMedia Demo Site LINK SHOULD BE PRESENT ON THE HOME PAGE OF rtMedia ACTUAL: rtMedia LINK is  NOT PRESENT ON THE HOME PAGE OF rtMedia. DETAILS:Exception Occurred:"+generalException.getLocalizedMessage();
            // File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) Config.driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);  
           // FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\failure.png")); 

        } finally {
            Assert.assertTrue(Login_Status.equalsIgnoreCase("PASS"), Login_Message);
        }   
    }
}
```

I wrote the above Java code for login functionality and now I want to create reports for whatever the result will be (pass or fail) and it should be stored in folder? I have no idea about the generating the reports and also I found the reports are automatically generated by TestNG itself but when we run another test it gets overwritten, that will not help for me. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways you can achieve this

1. If you're using XML report then you can implement IReporter and create a listener. You have to override a method called `generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites, List<ISuite> suites, String outputDirectory)` and you can have your own logic to save the output in a different folder everytime you run the test case.
2. There is an attribute in testNG called `fileFragmentationLevel` if you set it to 3 I think your report will not be overwritten. It's in XML reporter class
3. You can create a listener that will extend `TestListenerAdapter` and override `onStart(ITestContext testContext)` method to back up your testoutput folder everytime. But I don't prefer this method.

I prefer #1.